# Python Selenium AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-class

The problem is although i can see the method I'm calling, the error says I don't have a method the way I call. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\htuna\selenium-playground\src\query\ncts_query.py", line 21, in <module>
    query.query_press_key()
  File "C:\Users\htuna\selenium-playground\src\query\ncts_query.py", line 13, in query_press_key
    self.__chrome.press_key("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input",
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute '_Query__chrome'
```

I can use method from Chrome() classes in Ncts() classes however I can't use the same method under Query() class. Here is my code:

```
from src.query.ncts_query_data import QueryData
from src.login.ncts_login import Ncts
from src.browser.chrome import Chrome

class Query:

    def _init_(self, queryData: QueryData, ncts: Ncts, chrome: Chrome):
        self.__queryData = queryData
        self.__ncts = ncts
        self.__chrome = chrome

    def query_press_key(self):
        self.__chrome.press_key("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input",
                                "DENEME")

query = Query()
ncts = Ncts()

ncts.login()
ncts.open_guarentee_query()
query.query_press_key()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your class definition.

1. It should be `__init__` not `_init_`. (Double underscore)
2. You cannot access directly `__chrome` since you wrote it with double underscore (`__`). It means that it should not be accessed outside of class. It is similar to a private variable but not as private with other languages.

To fix your code here is a sample.

```py
from src.query.ncts_query_data import QueryData
from src.login.ncts_login import Ncts
from src.browser.chrome import Chrome

class Query:

    def __init__(self, queryData: QueryData, ncts: Ncts, chrome: Chrome):
        self.__queryData = queryData
        self.__ncts = ncts
        self.chrome = chrome

    def query_press_key(self):
        self.chrome.press_key("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input",
                                "DENEME")
```

Comment: I changed ```__init__``` and ```chrome``` owever it doesn't work properly. It was opening 3 Chrome browsers. I also changed my code that way: ```query = Query(queryData=QueryData, ncts=Ncts, chrome=Chrome)
ncts = Ncts()

ncts.login()
ncts.open_guarentee_query()
query.query_press_key()``` now it opens 1 Chrome browser but error says: ```TypeError: Chrome.press_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'```

Comment: Your first issue was `AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute '_Query__chrome'`, the changes fixed the issue since you are not encountering it anymore. The issue you encountered is another issue.

I would suggest you to read more about how python class works.